# Custom url theme for drupal

Tags: theming

We got site written on Drupal.

We want to make Nginx caching but there is one problem we met.

Nginx caching works perfect, but if user A will go to page `http://domain.com` and nginx cache it. User B use mobile theme `http://domain.com/?theme=mobile` and went to `http://domain.com/` , he will see desktop version instead of mobile version.

I want to make something like `http://domain.com/any/url/path` for desktop version and `http://domain.com/mobile/any/url/path`

Is it possible? Where can I found information about how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Drupal6 Have a look at [Mobile Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_tools) module.

> The Mobile Tools module provides Drupal developers with some tools to
>   assist in making adjustments to your site based on the visitor's
>   device.

Once you install the module you can define different paths for desktop and mobile, then browser will detect the device and redirect to corresponding path.
For Drupal 7 [Mobile Switch](https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_switch) module is the alternative

Comment: And that bypasses/works with Nginx caching automatically? Could you outline how? I'm struggling to see it. I'd also be wary of installing a dev only module for something so important

Comment: The module I have used is for Drupal 6, the  Mobile Switch module is for Drupal 7. I am not sure if it bypasses nginx cache.

Comment: It doesn't suits to me because I have not only mobile and desktop version but version for people with disabilities

Answer (score 1):

It was easily than I expect.

We use ThemeKey module so I added some rules depends on url like "`drupal:path visuallimpaired/%`" and just make my own plugin that use `hook_url_inbound_alter` and  `hook_url_outbound_alter` to add and remove prefixes, and it works.